# Converting 'anything' to string via TypeConverters

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, type-conversion

I'm trying to create an utility method which converts a value of any arbitary type to another type using a `TypeConverter`. However, when trying to convert something to string, the `TypeConverter` always fails.

```
private bool TryConvertType(object value, Type targetType, out object result) {
    result = null;
    if(value == null)
        return false;

    try {

        if(targetType.IsInstanceOfType(value)) {
            result = value;
            return true;
        }

        var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
        if(typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(value.GetType())) {
            result = typeConverter.ConvertFrom(value);
            return true;
        }
        ...
```

Given the `value` as type `bool` and the `targetType` `string`, the method `.CanConvertFrom()` always returns false. Why shouldn't it be possible to create a `string` from a `boolean` value? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Need more info on the error. But first a question what is wrong with .ToString()??

Comment: @BillRuhl The error is simply: The TypeDescriptor can't convert from a boolean to a string. (.CanConvertFrom() returns false). Nothing more. And, as you can see, the idea of the utlity method is to convert any value to another type. I just used string <-> bool in this example.

Comment: Well... again i'm not sure what your after but C# already does all this, if you call .ToString() on a bool value it will return "true" or "false". Not that certain about the TypeDescriptor class itself but one of the things your up against is memory allocation. To convert a boolean value to a string is one thing you'll just get true or false but going from string to boolean will not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `TypeConverter` backwards. Or rather, you are trying to use the `string` `TypeConverter` on a `bool`:

```
var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(targetType);
```

This gives you the `TypeConverter` for string, but the var you wish to convert is `bool`.  You also want to use `CanConvertTo` / `ConvertTo` for the actual conversion:

```
// get bool type TypeConverter
var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(value.GetType());
// can it convert a bool to string?
if (typeConverter.CanConvertTo(targetType))
{
    // joy!
    result = typeConverter.ConvertTo(value, targetType);
    return true;
}
```

Test code:

```
if (TryConvertType(b, t, out result))
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Output:

> True

Of course, `ToString()` already works on just about anything and everything.

Comment: _using the TypeConverter backwards_. How does one can know that this is even possible? Using a `StringConverter` to convert **FROM** `boolean` **TO** `string` sounds to me as the same as using a `BooleanConverter` to convert **TO** `string` **FROM** `boolean`. What where the .NET developers thinking when they designed that confusing API? Anyway, it works now, so thank you very much.

Comment: Strings are special. Remember, *every single type has a string representation*. If that weren't true, we wouldn't be able to display them on screen. It's why object has a ToString() function. To put these "to string" conversions in the StringConverter would make that a very large class indeed, and it would be out of date as soon as you created a new class. The correct place for these "to string" conversions is in the TypeConverter for the relevant type. In this case, the BooleanConverter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why, but looking at the source for `StringConverter` ([here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/StringConverter.cs,6961a91428d88db3))

```
public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
            if (sourceType == typeof(string)) {
                return true;
            }
            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }
```

It's deferring to the base `TypeConverter` class for any type except string; I couldn't get `CanConvertFrom` to return true for any type at all! I don't know *why* this is the case,but you could always do this:

```
try
{
     var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value,targetType);
     return convertedValue;
}
catch(FormatException fex)
{
    //can't convert for whatever reason.
}
```

> And as a bonus, I'll throw in the obligatory warning that wildly converting from one type to another may lead to explosions, there may be a better design to achieve your goal, etc, etc :)